# Should I reference the same template file in multiple templateUrl decorator on multiple components?

Tags: angular

I need to display a few reporting pages. The reports all have the same visual look and behavior. The main difference is the Page Header, and subtitle. The data differs from report to report but it is all tabular data. The template files for these reports are identical, except for the page header and subtitle.

I would like to remove the code duplication by making a common template and reference in all the reporting components' templateUrl decorator.

I've done it, it works just fine, and feels very elegant. But it seems to break the component nature of angular. I cannot find examples of this technique online, so I feel it's not "the right way to do things".

Is there another more preferred approach?

Before: report1.component.html (and report2.component.html, and report3.component.html, and report4.component.html) all contained the same code:

```html
<fancy-breadcrumb (linkClicked)="onLinkClicked($evet)></fancy-breadcrumb>
<div>Report 1</div>
<div>Sub Title 1</div>
<export-button title="Export Report" (click)="exportReport()"></export-button>

<!-- each component provides unique data in the follow div -->
<report-table [date]="data"></report-table>
```

repeat the above 3 more times in three different component.html files.

After: report-common.html

```html
<fancy-breadcrumb (linkClicked)="onLinkClicked($evet)></fancy-breadcrumb>
<div>{{ reportTitle }}</div>
<div>{{ reportSubTitle }}</div>
<export-button title="Export Report" (click)="exportReport()"></export-button>
<report-table [date]="data"></report-table>
```

report-1.component.ts, report-2.component.ts, report-3.component.ts, and report-4.component.ts all reference this 1 template file in their templateUrls. the reports have no  template.html files of their own.

Comment: Have you considered extracting the common parts into a shared component, then reuse that component on your individual report pages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The absolute easiest thing would be to create a shared component but this sounds like the perfect job for [Content Projection](https://angular.io/guide/content-projection). You can create a template component that then allows you to pass in items that are then used where/how you want.

report-container html

```html
<fancy-breadcrumb (linkClicked)="onLinkClicked($event)"></fancy-breadcrumb>
<div>{{title}}</div>
<div>{{subtitle}}</div>
<ng-content select="[customExportButton]"></ng-content>
<ng-content select="[reportTable]"></ng-content>
```

report-container ts

```js
export class ReportContainer {
  @Input() title: string;
  @Input() subtitle: string;
  ...
}
```

calling component

```html
<report-template title='Report 1 Title Text' subtitle='Subtitle Text Here'>
  <export-button customExportButton title="Export Report" (click)="exportReport()"></export-button>
  <report-table reportTable [date]="data"></report-table>
</report-template>
```

Comment: Thanks Chris for editing my response, I just used what DrFloyd5 posted so I didn't want to change too much and potentially break the code if he/she copy & pasted.

Comment: Thanks @Miles and @Chris. I went with a shared component. A lot of the visual properties and styles moved to the shared component which made other components lighter. I had some trouble with `@ViewChild` not being able to "reach" 2 components deep. But worked aroud that. Thanks for the guidance!

Comment: Typically for that, on the parent component you can set the encapsulation to none
import { Component, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent-component',
  templateUrl: './parent-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./parent-component.component.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})